# Share database with several microservices which use liquibase

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, liquibase

I have to migrate old Spring Boot microservices whiten in 2015 which are using liquibase with Oracle database.
So far from what I found all microservices use the same database url. This means only one database is used for every microservice.

Now I want to migrate the microservices using Postgres database. When I start different microservice I get message for different database scheme checksum. This is expected because the database migration scripts are executed by liquibase during miroservice statup.

What are the possible solutions to this problem? I see the same DB connection url link into every microservice which means the DB tables should be shared or there is another configuration that might be missing?

Comment: can you share the error which you see and and example of one changelog? I guess there is something like `dbms="oracle"` which causes the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that storing microservice databases in a single schema/database is not your end goal. So I think you might have big problems in the future if you use Liquibase this way.

What I mean?

If you move your microservices databases to other schemas or DB instances in the future, you will find that all metadata about the migration of all services is stored in one table maintained by Liquibase: `databasechangelog`. And distinguishing the data from this table will not be easy.

I think you should think about different Liquibase tables for each microservice. Luckily, Liquibase provides a [mechanism for this](https://contribute.liquibase.com/extensions-integrations/directory/integration-docs/springboot/springboot/):

| Spring Boot | Liquibase | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `spring.liquibase.database-change-log-lock-table` | `databaseChangeLogLockTableName` | Name of table to use for tracking concurrent Liquibase usage |
| `spring.liquibase.database-change-log-table` | `databaseChangeLogTableName` | Name of table to use for tracking change history |

For exmaple, you have services `S1`, `S2`, ... `SX`. Then `databasechangelog` tables can look like this:

- `databasechangelog-s1`
- `databasechangelog-s2`
- ...
- `databasechangelog-sx`

And of course you should do the same for the `databasechangeloglock` table.

This approach will automatically solve your problems with conflicting checksums. If I understood your problem correctly.

It can help you in the future. Just think about it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is identify whether the verification failure comes from microservices or Postgres itself - as it also has such mechanism.

What you want to do is run the following command [pg_verify_checksums](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgverifychecksums.html) - if all is dandy on that end, you can focus on the verification method your microservices use. There could be some discrepancy in verification methods, and whatever you have implemented could work with Liquidbase but not with Postgres, as Postgres uses page-level checksums rather than table-level checksums.